# How can I set a table to be already scrolled at a certain column when i load the html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that has a various number of columns depending on the number of months that are inputted from my database starting from a start_date and towards an end_date. I know as a variable the current_date and i need to make the table load with the x-scrollbar right on top of my current_date because the current date can be very far from the beginning of the table and I am supposed to scroll towards it.

[Click here to see my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ6wu.jpg)

Is there any possibility that I can set the x-scrollbar to start from a certain position?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as part of your question.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to add anchor tags to the columns you want to scroll to instantly. So if you have a column <td id="test"> you could easily call the website like this mydomain.com/#test and would land directly at the test column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>scrollTop demo</title>
  <style>
  div.demo {
    background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 3px solid #666;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  p {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="demo"><h1>lalala</h1><p>Hello</p></div>
 
<script>
$( "div.demo" ).scrollTop( 300 );
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

[jQuery scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)